# htaccess doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess rewrite URL as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^my-page\.html$ /my-page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^my-page/([^/]*)\.html$ /level1.php?num=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^my-page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /level2.php?level1=$1&level2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /level3.php?level3=$1 [L]
```

These rules above rewrite URLs from `mywebsite.com/my-page.php` to `mywebsite.com/my-page.html`.

Now, what I want to achieve is `mywebsite.com/my-page/` to be redirected to `mywebsite.com/my-page.php` (which in turn rewrites to `mywebsite.com/my-page.html`).

What I have tried, I created a directory "my-page" and tried to redirect requests from `mywebsite.com/my-page/` to `/my-page.html`.

I don't know what went wrong. I can see in the network tab that a request is made to `/my-page/` and gets rewritten to `mywebsite.com/my-page.htmlmy-page/`, which gives a 302 Status ☹

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use RedirectMatch to achieve this.

Redirect to my-page.php:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/my-page/ http://mywebsite.com/my-page.php
```

or straight away to my-page.html if this is your goal:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/my-page/ http://mywebsite.com/my-page.html
```

or, what will be best - change the code responsible for `mywebsite.com/my-page.htmlmy-page/`, but I can't see it in question you have asked :)

Comment: It works great!  `RedirectMatch 301 ^/my-page.htmlmy-page/ http://mywebsite.com/my-page.html` :)

Comment: glad I could help, but please remember that this is not a perfect solution, because it's domain-dependent for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Please give the following a try. Brief descriptions are found in the comments for each section.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Trim www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

# Redirect /my-page[/] to /my-page.html
# >> Note: change 302 to 301 to make permanent
RewriteRule ^my-page/?$ my-page.html [R=302,L]

# Allow existing files and directories
# Recommended to comment out the first line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite *.html to respective page
RewriteRule ^my-page.html$ my-page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^my-page/([^/]*).html$ level1.php?num=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^my-page/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ level2.php?level1=$1&level2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ level3.php?level3=$1 [L]
```

The important part here is that you do the required redirect before any other rewrites (except the `www.` removal).

Also, you previously had the two conditions which stated that if the request was not for a file or directory, then proceed with the next rule, but that wouldn't have accounted for the last two rules. As such, this version tells Apache to stop everything if the request is for an existing file or directory. I would recommend, for security purposes, that you comment out the line that checks for existing directories.

Comment: I tried as suggested above, it doesn't work. I am facing the same problem, when I navigate to **http://mywebsite.com/my-page/** , I get redirected to **http://mywebsite.com/my-page.htmlmy-page/** which gives me a 302 Not Found Status

Comment: I have updated to make the trailing slash optional, but I don't think that matters here. All I can think of is cache. Have you cleared it? And what is 302 Not Found? 302's message is 'Found'.